# flutter doctor: device is offline

Tags: flutter, adb

After running Flutter doctor to see why my physical LG G6 device was not being picked up, I found out that the "Device is offline".

I've tried googling around, and unplugging and re plugging the device. 
Nothing seems to work.

What does this mean? My device does have debug enable, and it's definitely connecting to the pc and flutter definitely see it.

Comment: Did you try changing the phone connection (on the usb notification) from charging to file transfer?

Comment: Yes I've tried that. Still doesn't work. All that does is make it disappear completely from the flutter devices list

Comment: Tried another USB cable and port?  Also, it's probably not a flutter issue, rather a connection issue.

Comment: for me, it finally started working when I started using my PCs front USB (2.0) slot.
Read about that here: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12491/adb-constantly-disconnects-shows-device-offline

Answer (score 7):

It could be a problem with the USB cable.

Had the same problem, then tried another cable, plugged in the same port as the old cable, and it didn't go offline.

If I plug in the old cable, the same problem happens: it goes offline after some time, even though it's connected, and I can see my device's files in Windows.

Comment: That fixed it for me. Good call.

Comment: In my case, restarting the PC & then trying works